# How to Open Front and Back camera through intent in android?

Tags: android, camera, android-camera-intent

We implement camera with intent it's working fine in micromax480p version 5.1 but when we used in Nexus7 version 6.1 by that time camera is opened but i want to open some times Front and somr times Back is it possible to open according to as we need.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

    fileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);
    //intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
    //intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    if(camera == 1) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1) {
            //intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            intent.putExtra("android.intent.extras.CAMERA_FACING", android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT);
            intent.putExtra("android.intent.extras.LENS_FACING_FRONT", 1);
            intent.putExtra("android.intent.extra.USE_FRONT_CAMERA", true);

        } else {
            intent.putExtra("android.intent.extras.CAMERA_FACING", 1);
        }
    }


    // start the image capture Intent
    startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode);
```

I used like this but it's open defaultly what ever we used camera(front and back) previously.thanks. sorry for my weak English comm.

Comment: I used also camera API through Surfaceview but what will happen when we open camera and take the picture after that i can not see the preview whether this image is right or not i.e. user confirmation.because of that i used camera app and when user take picture after that they confirm then only we will save else reject it.

Comment: as @gowtham stated use the nested `if` to wrap them based on your requirement.You also use `switch`.

Answer (score 4):

To open the **back** camera:-

```
val cameraIntent = Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, REQUEST_CODE_CAMERA)
```

To open the **front** camera:-

```
val cameraIntent = Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
when {
     Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1 && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.O -> {
         cameraIntent.putExtra("android.intent.extras.CAMERA_FACING", CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING_FRONT)  // Tested on API 24 Android version 7.0(Samsung S6)
     }
     Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O -> {
         cameraIntent.putExtra("android.intent.extras.CAMERA_FACING", CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING_FRONT) // Tested on API 27 Android version 8.0(Nexus 6P)
         cameraIntent.putExtra("android.intent.extra.USE_FRONT_CAMERA", true)
     }
     else -> cameraIntent.putExtra("android.intent.extras.CAMERA_FACING", 1)  // Tested API 21 Android version 5.0.1(Samsung S4)
}
startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, REQUEST_CODE_CAMERA)
```

I could not make it work for API 28 and above. Also, opening the front camera directly is not possible in some devices(depends on the manufacturer).

Comment: This does not opens front camera in Samsung M01 having android 10. any solution ?

Comment: it's not working for me. i'm trying to set back camera as default and open only this way but unsuccessfully. my device opens last-used camera for some reason

Answer (score 2):

Try the code below

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1) { 
    intent.putExtra("android.intent.extras.LENS_FACING_FRONT", 1);
} else { 
    intent.putExtra("android.intent.extras.CAMERA_FACING", 1); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To call the **Front** camera you can use:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);    
intent.putExtra("android.intent.extras.CAMERA_FACING", 1);
```

To call the **Back** camera you can use:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
startActivity(intent);
```

And you need to set the permission for the camera in your AndroidManifest.xml:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"> </uses-permission>
```

Comment: Use Condition, if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1) { intent.putExtra("android.intent.extras.LENS_FACING_FRONT", 1); } else { intent.putExtra("android.intent.extras.CAMERA_FACING", 1); } Working on a Nexus 5 5.1 (if case) and a Samsung S4 5.0.1 (else case)

Comment: Its not official

Comment: It is not working. Tested samsung devices and OS 9!!

Comment: for front camera you need to use intent.putExtra("android.intent.extras.CAMERA_FACING", CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING_FRONT)//LENS_FACING_FRONT = 0

Answer (score 1):

This work for me

```
btn_camera.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1) {
                    intent.putExtra("android.intent.extras.CAMERA_FACING", android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT);
                    intent.putExtra("android.intent.extras.LENS_FACING_FRONT", 1);
                    intent.putExtra("android.intent.extra.USE_FRONT_CAMERA", true);
                } else {
                    intent.putExtra("android.intent.extras.CAMERA_FACING", 1);
                }

                Uri fileUri = // your fileUri

                if(fileUri == null) {
                    Toasty.error(MainActivity.this, "Erro diretorio", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT, true).show();
                } else {

                    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);
                }
                startActivityForResult(intent, 100);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this for open the back camera

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE_SECURE );
```

Answer (score 0):

Android SDK <= 2.2 only supports use of a single camera (the first back-facing camera). For 2.3+, you can loop through the cameras and figure out which is the front facing one (if available). It'd be something like...

```
Camera cam = null;
Camera.CameraInfo cameraInfo = new Camera.CameraInfo();
for (int camNo = 0; camNo < Camera.getNumberOfCameras(); camNo++) {
    CameraInfo camInfo = new CameraInfo();
    Camera.getCameraInfo(camNo, camInfo);
    if (camInfo.facing.equals(Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT)) {
        cam = Camera.open(camNo);
    }
}
if (cam == null) {
   // no front-facing camera, use the first back-facing camera instead.
   // you may instead wish to inform the user of an error here...
   cam = Camera.open();
}
// ... do stuff with Camera cam ...
```

You also need to add these to your manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.front" android:required="false" />
```

Comment: Here i can open front camera but how to see the recent taken picture and confirm then only it's going to save in device else remove and give retake option to take picture.

Comment: refer this project : https://github.com/wishygupta/Front-Camera-Android

Comment: Most Welcome! If this answer is really works for you then make its as acceptable!