# How to open Back / Rear camera in android using intent

Tags: android, android-intent, android-camera

I am fairly new to android and I need to open the rear camera from my application currently I am using the intent method to open the camera and capture an image. but the problem is that whenever I leave the stock application on the camera from my application opens in the same camera setting. for example, if I open the front camera in my default application, the app will also open the front camera whereas I need to only open the rear camera.
how do I fix this, I have been looking at multiple options but none seem to work.

please help thanks in advance.

my code for the intent.

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
 startActivityForResult(intent,0);
```

Comment: You will find your answer here [How to Open Front and Back camera through intent in android](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43841738/6652743)

Comment: @NayanSarder i have tried this method but it does not work