# How do I force the back camera on Android using an intent?

Tags: android

You can select the default camera on Android by opening the default Camera app and selecting the camera you want to use. This camera then becomes the default camera. Using the code below select the default camera.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
```

How do I force the use of the back camera using an Intent?

Comment: As far as I know, there is no official way to select the back camera by using an intent. Someone tried this below, but it would not always work on any devices or OS. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43841738/how-to-open-front-and-back-camera-through-intent-in-android