# Intent to open front camera not working for Android 12 and below

Tags: android, kotlin, android-camera

I am trying to open the front camera using intent. For that, I am using this extra

```
val intent = Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE)
intent.putExtra("android.intent.extras.CAMERA_FACING", 1)
```

This is working in Android 13+ devices, but I tried to use multiple ways to open the front camera in Android 12 and below:

```
intent.putExtra("com.google.assistant.extra.USE_FRONT_CAMERA", true)
intent.putExtra("android.intent.extra.USE_FRONT_CAMERA", true)
intent.putExtra("android.intent.extras.LENS_FACING_FRONT", 1)
```

I also have tried with 0 as camera-facing Extras

```
intent.putExtra("android.intent.extras.CAMERA_FACING", 0)
```

But still, it's not working.

I am trying to record video from the device camera, with the front camera open.

I have searched a lot but could not find how to do it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Open Front and Back camera through intent in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43841738/how-to-open-front-and-back-camera-through-intent-in-android)

Answer (score 1):

> This is working in Android 13+ devices

It is working with the specific camera apps that you happened to test with on those devices.

There are tens of thousands of Android device models. There will be dozens, if not hundreds, of pre-installed camera apps on those models. There are countless more camera apps available on the Play Store and elsewhere. What extras and Intents that those apps honor are up to the developers of those apps. The OS version does not matter.

There is no extra documented [on `MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/provider/MediaStore?hl=en#action_video_capture) for controlling which camera the camera app uses for video capture. There is no requirement for any camera app to support undocumented extras.

If you need to control the camera used for video capture, use CameraX or another camera library and implement the video recording directly in your app.